# Why does this query take so long in Entity Framework, when it's so fast in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I have a table named GeographicalLocations, which contains about 57K rows. If I run the following query in SQL Server Management Studio, it takes about 1-2 seconds to complete...

```
select * from GeographicalLocations where Active=1
```

If I do the equivalent in LinqPad, it takes about 2-3 seconds...

```
GeographicalLocations.Where (gl => gl.Active)
```

However, the same code in a repository that uses EF4 takes about 10-11 seconds...

```
List<GeographicalLocation> geographicalLocations = new SalesTrackerCRMEntities()
  .CreateObjectSet<GeographicalLocation>()
  .Where(g => g.Active)
  .ToList();
```

By the way, we're stuck with EF4 for the moment, so please don't suggest upgrading. I'd love to, but there are other factors that are stopping us for the moment.

Any idea how I can speed this up? The users are complaining about the slow response. It's obviously not the database, as the SQL query itself is very fast. It looks like something to do with EF, but I don't know what.

I ran SQL Profiler on it, and could see the SQL that was sent. That took less than a second to run in SSMS, but the profiler showed 10 a second gap between the start and end of the batch. Not sure what's going on here, as I would have thought that EF would pull out all the data, then materialise it into entities, but it looks like it might be doing it as it goes along.

Anyway, I would be grateful for any ideas as to how I can improve the performance here.

Comment: Create context separately and try again. Creating context takes time

Comment: Tried that,didn't make any difference. The query takes this long even with an existing context. Any other ideas? Thx

Comment: Run profiler (DotTrace for instance, it's free for 30 days) and see where is the bottleneck.

Comment: When you state, "If I run the following query in SQL Server Management Studio, it takes about 1-2 seconds to complete..." - is that for results to start coming into your results pane - or - for the query to complete (all records are received, a record count is provided, and the query timer is stopped)?

Comment: @Mike, all results returned, record count provided and the query timer stopped.

Comment: @RomanPushkin the problem is that the code I have written is minimal, so any bottleneck will be in the EF code itself. I don't see how running a profiler will help. What I need to do is find out if there's a way of doing this so that EF will load the data faster. Maybe I missed the point of your reply. Thx.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel, just profile it. You'll see the name of the method running in EF. You'll be able to narrow it down. I had issue before, but it was a little bit different. I profiled, and found I had perfomance issues because of graph recalculation.

Comment: How many rows are returned? Is IsActive nullable?

Comment: Turned out that tracking was killing the performance. Please see the answer I just posted. Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much mucking mucking around, I discovered that the following takes less than 200ms (compared to about 11 seconds before)...

```
var geographicalLocations = getContext().CreateObjectSet<GeographicalLocation>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(g => g.Active).ToList()
```

The disadvantage to this is that it won't load related entities, so you have to load them manually afterwards, but it gives such an immense performance boost that it was well worth it (in this case at least).

You would have to assess each case individually to see if the extra speed is worth the extra code.

Hope this helps. Thanks to all for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

When using LINQ expressions against a DbSet you're taking advantage of the IQueryable interface.  IQueryables are evaluated into SQL statements that are then executed against your database.  If you want to speed up performance you can query the DbSet property with a raw SQL statement like this:

`var locations = db.GeographicalLocations.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM GeographicalLocations WHERE Active = 1").ToList();`

Comment: Dropping down to SQL is the nuclear option. I'd exhaust other options first.

Comment: Like usr said, inserting SQL is really not a good idea. However, I found out that turning off tracking gave exactly the same performance boost, see my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.